# Swing - How to limit my app to screen size

Tags: java, swing, window, screen

In my app, I need a window to display an image viewer, with the following size constraints:

- If the image is small, the window adjusts its size to the image and does not display scrollbars
- If the image is large, the window also adjusts, but the **whole app** should remain visible on screen, with scrollbars appearing around the image if needed

The goal is that the UI above and below the image remains visible.

I wrote the following code for demo, but with large images, the app always grows larger than the screen...

Any idea what the correct way would be ?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ScrollTest {
    private static final int IMG_WIDTH = 2000; // or 500
    private static final int IMG_HEIGHT = 2000; // or 500

    // Unsuccessful attempts:
    private static void limitAppSize(JFrame frame) {
        frame.setMaximumSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
//        frame.setPreferredSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        frame.pack();
    }

    public static void addComponentsToPane(Container container) {
        container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JPanel imagePanel = new JPanel() {
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                // Image replaced by a shape for demonstration purpose
                g2d.drawOval(0,0, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT);
            }
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT);
            }
            public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
                return new Dimension(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT);
            }
        };

        JScrollPane scrollableImagePanel = new JScrollPane(imagePanel);
        container.add(new JLabel("This would be a toolbar menu with multiple lines"));
        container.add(scrollableImagePanel);
        container.add(new JLabel("This would be a status bar"));
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ScrollTest");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());
        limitAppSize(frame);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGUI());
    }
}
```

Comment: *"JPanel imagePanel = new JPanel() {.." Why not use a `JLabel` instead?

Comment: Well, I tend to think JLabels are for labels and JPanels are for plain panels, but I see many examples where JLabels are used as lightweight panels indeed. I admit I don't really get the pros and cons but I guess asking here would go off topic, so I'll do my homework :-). 
Unless it's particularly relevant for sizing issues ?

Comment: OK, got it: JPanel is is a "branch" in the component hierarchy and can contain child components, JLabel is a "leaf" in the component tree and is thus more lighweight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame will resize to the screen size, ignoring the size of the task bar.

To take the task bar into account you can use:

```
frame.pack();

Dimension preferred = frame.getSize();
GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
Rectangle bounds = env.getMaximumWindowBounds();

preferred.width = preferred.width > bounds.width ? bounds.width : preferred.width;
preferred.height = preferred.height > bounds.height ? bounds.height : preferred.height;

frame.setSize( preferred );
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed ! Thanks. I was trying to give hints to the Layout Manager so that it finds out the right size by himself, but just computing the Min myself and using setSize() to force it makes sense of course. 

And good to know about the getMaximumWindowBounds() API call !

Comment: Update: after integrating that change, I'm running into a new issue due to the actual layout I'm using. Care to check out the new version ? Thanks.

Comment: That is a different question and should be posted in a separate thread to get the best chance of an answer.

Comment: You're right. Rolled back my edit and posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62021983/swing-jscollarea-in-gridbaglayout-collapses-when-resizing